# Can I have both Win10 sdk and WP8.1 sdk both in 2015

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, windows-10, windows-10-mobile

I uninstalled VS2013 without uninstalling WP8.1 with update 1 SDK and then installed VS2015 community but I can't find Win10 SDK now. Is it because I have WP8.1 SDK installed? Can I have both SDKs installed in VS2015?

Added: I have both SDKs installed, but when I create new projects, I can only find WP8 option, as shown below:

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have both SDKs installed with VS2015. During installation you  have to choose the components. If you have already installed, go to Programms & Settings and choose Visual Studio 2015. Select "Change" to modify the existing installation. In the Installation dialog select the checkboxes for the SDKs as shown in the picture.

[image]

You will find the templates for Windows 10 under Windows--> Universal. 
They are not called "Windows 10 apps" but these templates are the project templates for apps for Windows 10 which will run on all Windows 10 devices including Phone (aka Windows 10 Mobile). Right now only one tempate exists (Blank App). See Screenshot below.
[image]

Comment: Thanks. I did install all the packages as indicated in your screenshot. But when I create a new project, I can only find options for WP8.1 universal apps. There's no option for me to create Win10 projects. Where do I enable the option for Win10?

Comment: See my edited answer. You can find them under the Windows--> Universal node.